# HTML tags are popping up beneath the images in my wordpress posts

Tags: html-tag-summary

I am new to this forum. I am trying to build my affiliate website. But i am facing a number of issues inside.

1. HTML Tags pop up beneath the images (from Amazon URLs) when I try to load my webpage.
2. I am not able to see the mobile menu on my mobile screen when I try to view my website on mobile.

Thanks
Satnam Singh [HTML Tags beneath images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwmL7.png)

I tried working with customer care support of HOSTINGER but they were not able to help me even working with them for 3 days.

1. I have tried reinserting the HTML tags from AMAZON.
2. Tried making some changes in block settings (Post Editing)